# Magento - "created_at" field does not set automatically with the rest of the data

Tags: php, date, magento, magento-1.9

I have created a module which saves some data into the custom tables. Both tables have "created_at" and "updated_at" fields in them. But when I save the data into any if these tables "created_at" field does not set automatically.

Here is my code:
**Sql script:**

```sql
->addColumn(
    'created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array('nullable' => true,), 'Created At'
)
->addColumn(
    'updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array('nullable' => true,), 'Updated At'
)
```

**Model.php**

```php
class my_Module extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
        public function addMyList($customerId, $name)
        {
            $this->setData(
                array(
                    'b2b_customer_id' => $customerId,
                    'name' => $name,
                )
            );
            $this->save();
            return;
        }
}
```

I have looked into other posts but most of them set this "created_at" filed along with the rest of the data in the function. Which is not what exactly I want because I think Magento should handle it itself.

But please let me know if I am thinking wrong or the code is wrong somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Magento is very special in some ways. Setting `created_at` and `updated_at` automatically is a good idea - most of the modern frameworks, i. e. Laravel, support that.

Magento does not set `created_at` and `updated_at` automatically.

There is a `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Abstract::_prepareDataForSave()` method - so in case you have a resource model and this extends this class you can/should call this method to get your `created_at` and `updated_at` set correctly.

```php
/**
 * Prepare data for save
 *
 * @param Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object
 * @return array
 */
protected function _prepareDataForSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    $currentTime = Varien_Date::now();
    if ((!$object->getId() || $object->isObjectNew()) && !$object->getCreatedAt()) {
        $object->setCreatedAt($currentTime);
    }
    $object->setUpdatedAt($currentTime);
    $data = parent::_prepareDataForSave($object);
    return $data;
}
```

You still can set it manually if you want.

Answer (score 2):

In your model: `Mynamespace_mymodule_model_Mymodel`, just add the `_beforeSave()` function .

```
Mynamespace_mymodule_model_Mymodel extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract

{ 
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('mynamespace_mymodule/myname');
    }

    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        parent::_beforeSave();
        $now = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate();
        if ($this->isObjectNew()) {
            $this->setCreatedAt($now);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```